# Prevent indexing of site search results

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, robots.txt, noindex

Users have the ability to search on my site. This function renders a search results page that has occasionally been indexed by google and served in SERPs. Normally this is not an issue, but when documents are updated users need to see the most recent information and sometimes stale content/files are index higher than the current information.

The solution would be: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` in the `head` of my search results page. My site is templated, including a base template that has `head` in it, so the same `head` gets served for every page. I can't put a `noindex` in there without some sort of conditional logic that checks if the URL is for a search page, which seems real hacky.

I could create the `noindex` meta element dynamically with javascript inside my search page template, [but someone has brought up that this is pointless because crawlers will crawl only the pre-processed markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977060/dynamically-creating-noindex-meta-tags-for-certain-urls). **Is this the case?**

Alternatively, I could add a `disallow` in my `robots.txt`, [but Google has said this isn't a great method](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) (2nd paragraph, bold). **Any insight on this?**

**Am I stuck using conditional logic in the `head` of my base template?**

Comment: Why would the noindex tag have to be created dynamically with JavaScript?   Couldn't you just edit the search page template to put it in directly?

Comment: Disallow in robots.txt mostly stops indexing.   If Google can't crawl it, Google won't usually index it.  The only exceptions are when there are a bunch of external links to it.

Comment: According to MOZ, Google should see your meta robots insert using JS just fine. As well, the second Google link bold statement does not make sense even for Google. This is precisely what the robots.txt file is for! Google is referring to the idiot policy of listing linked to pages (dangling links) for a period until the page is fetched or the link is found to be broken. Being blocked via robots should remove the SERP link in time. You can use your search template and simply place your meta robots tag there. I would do that and use robots.txt. Cheers!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was under the impression `meta` tags are only allowed inside the `head` element. A cursory search says that's not entirely true, but it still seems hacky, i.e. broken markup.

Comment: Why couldn't you edit the meta tag into the head element of your search page?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The templates are nested, with the `head` in the base template. I've just went ahead and created a conditional in the base template to include the `meta` tag when necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this could very well be the case regarding the pre-processed markup. I'm not aware of any ironclad evidence on this, but I would consider it risky to use the JS solution.

In this specific case disallowing via robots.txt is probably your best solution as it's the solution that Google themselves suggest. Keep in mind that I wasn't able to find that bit of quoted text on the quoted URL though.

"Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search results pages or other auto-generated pages that don’t add much value for users coming from search engines." (http://searchengineland.com/google-warning-against-letting-your-search-results-get-indexed-10709).

Comment: The actually quote from Google about robots.txt on that page is "You should not use robots.txt as a means to hide your web pages from Google Search results."